# How to wait for a boolean without looping (using any kind of wait / semaphore / event / mutex, etc)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

I need to stop a thread until another thread sets a boolean value **and I don't want to share between them an event**.

What I currently have is the following code using a Sleep (and that's the code I want to change):

```
while (!_engine.IsReadyToStop())
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Properties.Settings.Default.IntervalForCheckingEngine); 
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT TO CLARIFY THINGS:**

There is an object called _engine of a class that I don't own. I cannot modify it, that's why I don't want to share an event between them. I need to wait until a method of that class returns true.

Comment: Why don't you want to share an event? There are two ways to do what you want: events or spinning.

Comment: You want to share a boolean value but not an event. Why? What is the difference?

Comment: `I need to wait until a method of that class returns true.` So what do you expect from us. Just loop as you already do.

Comment: The title of the question is crystal clear I think: How to wait for a boolean without looping. If that cannot be done a "you cant'" will be the right answer. I'm not sure if this can or cannot be done.

Comment: OK you get the answer. No you can't

Comment: @SoMoS: But what is going on inside that method? Is it spawning a thread?

Comment: @Tudor: yeah, the engine runs on its own thread.

Comment: Well if you cannot change that class and the only way it communicates termination is with that boolean then I'm afraid you can't do anything but this spinning.

Comment: It would have been friendlier if the 'engine' thing had called an 'OnReadyToStop' event, instead of supplying this silly polling method, but you seem to be stuck with it.  Really need an engine rebuild..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`SpinWait.SpinUntil` is the right answer, regardless where you're gonna place this code. SpinUntil offers ["a nice mix of spinning, yielding, and sleeping in between invocations"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/spinwait-spinuntil-for-unit-testing/).

Comment: Not as good as a lock but seems the only possible way of doing it currently and much better that manually waiting.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `C# 4.0`, you can use:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => SomeCall(..));
t.Wait();
```

By using [Task.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx) method.

If you have more than one task run one after another, you can use [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx):

```
 Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew (() =>SomeCall(..)).
                                ContinueWith(ExecuteAfterThisTaskFinishes(...);
 t.Wait();
```

Comment: What is the point of spawning a task and immediately joining it? And I don't think this was the OP's question.

Comment: @Tudor: I had a doubt on this too, so add add also explanation about `ContinueWith`

Comment: I hope that now the question is more clear. My bad if it was not at the fist shot.

Comment: As the problem is not waiting a task to end but waiting until a value is set I think the proposed solution is not applicable. Makes sense?

Comment: @SoMoS: as your request is **only** waiting for the bollean change, that answer of L.B makes more sence. Just at the moment you set the boolean, `Set` event from the thread.

Comment: @SoMoS: like stuff for readin can have a look on *really* comprehensive guide: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) of `LinqPad` creator.

Answer (score 4):

declare as

```
 AutoResetEvent _ReadyToStop = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

and use as

```
 _ReadyToStop.WaitOne();
```

and

```
 _ReadyToStop.Set();
```

For more info see the [Synchronization Primitives in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964.aspx)

Comment: Ready to stop is a method that returns a boolean and that method is used at several places, that's why I said that I don't want to share an event between them, so as far as I know your answer is not valid.

Comment: @SoMoS funny, then use another name

Comment: ReadyToStop is just the name he gave to the AutoResetEvent variable.

Comment: I hope that now the question is more clear. My bad if it was not at the fist shot.

Answer (score 0):

A condition variable is the synchronization primitive you can use for waiting on a condition.

It does not natively exist in .NET. But the following [link](https://github.com/CodeExMachina/ConditionVariable) provides 100% managed code for a condition variable class implemented in terms of SemaphoreSlim, AutoResetEvent and Monitor classes. It allows thread to wait on a condition. And can wake up one or more threads when condition is satisfied. In addition, it supports timeouts and CancellationTokens.

To wait on a condition you write code similar to the following:

```
object queueLock = new object();

ConditionVariable notEmptyCondition = new ConditionVariable();

T Take() {

  lock(queueLock) {

    while(queue.Count == 0) {

      // wait for queue to be not empty
      notEmptyCondition.Wait(queueLock);
    }

    T item = queue.Dequeue();

    if(queue.Count < 100) {

      // notify producer queue not full anymore
      notFullCondition.Pulse();
    }

    return item;
  }
}
```

Then in another thread you can wake up one or more threads waiting on condition.

```
lock(queueLock) {

  //..add item here

  notEmptyCondition.Pulse(); // or PulseAll
}
```

Comment: .NET has monitors separate condition variable is not needed, unless you need to share multiple condition variables with the same lock, but I doubt this is what OP needs.